# editing multiple child records while accessing values of other attributes of said record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

For class

```
class Product
  has_many :productunits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :productunits

class Productunit 
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :unit

  validates :product_id, presence: true
  validates :unit_id, presence: true
```

the following form is meant **only** to update existing records (of what is effectively a join table), while formatting the fields in columns (one column per child) and effecting some view logic on whether the field should be shown or not.

```
<div class='grid-x grid-margin-x'>
  <%= f.fields_for :productunits do |price_fields| %>
    <div class='cell small-2 text-right'>
      <h4><%# productunit.unit.name %> </h4>
      <%# if productunit.unit.capacity == 2 %
      2 <%= label %> <%= price_fields.number_field :price2 %>
      <%# end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

However a number problems are arising:

1. I cannot invoke the value of an attribute of record being edited (say `productunit.unit.capacity`)
2. The natural break in child records is not accessible to html tags for formatting (`<div class='cell [...]`).  Worse, rails is throwing the child record id outside the div definition `</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="product[productunits_attributes][1][id]" id="product_productunits_attributes_1_id" />
    <div class='cell small-2 text-right'>`
3. submitting the form returns an error `Productunits unit can't be blank`which would be fair for a new record, but is definitely not expected when editing an existing one.

Unfortunately, the [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) is thin in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I cannot invoke the value of an attribute of record being edited

You can get the object wrapped by a form builder or input builder though the object method:

```
<div class='grid-x grid-margin-x'>
  <%= f.fields_for :productunits do |price_fields| %>
    <div class='cell small-2 text-right'>
      <h4><%= price_fields.object.unit.name %> </h4>
      <% if price_fields.object.unit.capacity == 2 %
      2 <%= price_fields.label :price2 %> <%= price_fields.number_field :price2 %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>      
</div>
```

> 2 The natural break in child records is not accessible to html tags
>   for formatting...

`fields_for` just iterates through the child records. Its just a loop. I'm guessing you just have broken html like a stray `</div>` tag or whatever you're doing with `<%= label %>`.

> submitting the form returns an error Productunits unit can't be blankwhich would be fair for a new record, but is definitely not expected when editing an existing one.

You're not passing a id for the unit. Rails does not do this automatically. Either use a hidden input or the collection helpers.

```
<div class='grid-x grid-margin-x'>
  <%= f.fields_for :productunits do |price_fields| %>
    <div class='cell small-2 text-right'>
      <h4><%= price_fields.object.unit.name %> </h4>
      <% if price_fields.object.unit.capacity == 2 %
      2 <%= price_fields.label :price2 %> <%= price_fields.number_field :price2 %>
      <% end %>
      <%= price_fields.collection_select(:unit_id, Unit.all, :id, :name) %> 
      # or
      <%= price_fields.hidden_field(:unit_id) %> 
    </div>
  <% end %>      
</div>
```

---

On a side note you should name your model `ProductUnit`, your table `product_units` and use `product_unit` everywhere else. [See the Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming-conventions).

Comment: Calling `object` method did the trick to solve all 3 issues.  The rendered html still has the id submission `</div>
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="product[productunits_attributes][1][id]" id="product_productunits_attributes_1_id" />` generated by rails (outside of html column definition but of no consequence); it is necessary for rails to recognize the record associated with the array's member so I see why it is rendered.

Comment: Yes, I am consciously un-stylish for this; although I know not german, I see the sense in hooking monikers up together like wagons in a train; it makes more immediate sense to me to not parse camelCasing_and_underscores for classes and tables... my quirk!